# D8 User group not seeing content

Tags: 8, users

Drupal 8.4 - I can't seem to figure out why when my one user group accounts are logged in, anything that uses slick slider or owl slider is completely removed from view and can't be seen. I though it was a permissions issue but nothing in there seems to even give that option as a permission. When I'm logged into my admin account, I see everything fine. Does anyone have any idea what may be causing this or have run into this before?

Comment: What are sub-user accounts?

Comment: Just a user account that doen't have admin permissions.